# Evaluating $P'/P$ without overflow

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, algorithms

Given a "large" complex number $x$ and a polynomial function $f$ (with "small" coefficients and degree), I'd like to compute $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ in a way that avoids "very large" intermediate results like $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$. The desired ratio is roughly just $\frac{\deg f}x$, so I'm hoping for an algorithm that avoids intermediate values much larger than $x^2$.

I've noticed that if $f(x)=\prod_i(x-r_i)$, then by the product rule, $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_i\frac1{x-r_i}$. This would be a nice computation, but I don't know the roots of $f$. Is there something like this I can do with just the coefficients? Does it help if I have $f'$ (but not $f$) in factored form?

Answer (score 2):

If you write
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\,x^k$$ using the long division you would have an approximation for large values of $x$
$$\frac{f_n'(x)}{f_n(x)}\sim\frac n x-\frac{a_{n-1} } {a_n } \frac 1{x^2}+\frac{a_{n-1}^2 -2\,a_{n-2}\,a_n} {a_n ^2} \frac 1{x^3}+\cdots$$ which is similar to what you wrote in your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved this by computing $\frac{x^{-d}f'(x)}{x^{-d}f(x)}$, viewing the numerator and denominator as polynomials in $x^{-1}$. This way, when $x$ is large, the insignificant terms vanish while the dominant terms stay at a reasonable size.